# Data processing puzzle/headache

Tags: c#, csv

I have a CSV file I need to process which is a bit of a nightmare. Esentially it is the following

```
"Id","Name","Description"
"1","Test1","Test description text"
"2","Test2","<doc><style>body{font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";}</style><p class="test_class"
name="test_name">Lots of word xdoc content here.</p></doc>"
"guid-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx","Test3","Test description text 3"
```

I'm using the [File Helpers](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/) library to process the CSV rather than reinvent the wheel. However, due to the description field containing unescaped Word xdoc xml which contains quotes it's getting rather confused when it comes to the start and end points of each record.

The following is an example mapping class.

```
[DelimitedRecord(","), IgnoreFirst(1), IgnoreEmptyLines()]
public class CSVDoc
{
    #region Properties
    [FieldQuoted('"', QuoteMode.AlwaysQuoted), FieldTrim(TrimMode.Both)]
    public string Id;
    [FieldQuoted('"', QuoteMode.AlwaysQuoted), FieldTrim(TrimMode.Both)]
    public string Name;
    [FieldQuoted('"', QuoteMode.AlwaysQuoted), FieldTrim(TrimMode.Both)]
    public string Description;
    [FieldQuoted('"', QuoteMode.AlwaysQuoted), FieldTrim(TrimMode.Both)]
}
```

I considered (despite my hate of regex for this kind of task) replacing all `"` with `'` and then using `((?<=(^|',))'|'(?=($|,')))` pattern to replace all `'` with `"` at the start and end of lines and where they are formatted `','`. However, the dirty file contains some lines which end with a `"` and some css style attributes which are formatted `","`

So now I'm left scratching my head trying to figure out how to do this and how it can be automated.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you not ask for a _clean/valid_ data source?

Comment: Don't use FileHelpers. Just code up a simple import yourself. It's only 3 columns. Parse out the first two normally, then treat the  remaining as the final description column.

Comment: I'm planning on asking for a cleaned source however I'm not sure as to what the source system is capable of so trying to find an alternative just in case. Just getting the description field in the first place took long enough. The secondary problem is all the data is user generated and I don't believe there is much restriction put on the users (sadly)

My example is 3 columns to demonstrate the problem, the actual data is many more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to have to re-invent the wheel, because that's not valid CSV or indeed a reasonable file at all - it doesn't have any sort of provably consistent escaping rules (e.g. we don't know if the plain-text columns are escaped correctly or not).

Your best bet is to ask the person producing this to fix the bug, it should be e.g.:

```
"2","Test2","<doc><style>body{font-family:""Calibri"",""sans-serif"";}</style><p class=""test_class""
name=""test_name"">Lots of word xdoc content here.</p></doc>"
```

Which your parser should handle fine, and which should not be hard for them to produce in a simple and efficient manner.

Failing that, you'll have to hand-code the parser to:

1. Read a line.
2. Check for unescaped " (any `"`that isn't followed by a `"` a `,` or whitespace.
3. If none found, parse as CSV.
4. If any found, parse as this horrible thing until you hit the line ending with "

It may be easier to look for `<` if that is consistently not used in the other lines. Or perhaps for `<doc` if it consistently identifies the correct rows.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind doing some pre-processing before, you can change the first and second "," to "|" and then use FileHelper to parse the file normally (Assuming you don't have | in the last column where there are HTML tags)

The pre-processing could be something like (Simple pseudo code) :

```
var sb = new StringBuilder()
var regex = new Regex("\",\"");
foreach(string line in textFileLines)
{
   sb.AppendLine(regex.Replace(line , "\"|\"", 2));
}
```

Comment: There is much more data (both columns and rows) in the actual data so I cannot rely on replacing specific items. Thanks anyway

Comment: Fixing the source file then seems to be the easiest option, otherwise as Jon Hanna mentioned you will need to write bunch of specific rules and conditions for parsing the file.

Answer (score 0):

I worked on the CSV-1203 File Format standard a few months ago, so the first thing to realise is that you're not dealing with a CSV file - even though it's named "xyz.CSV".

As said by others here, it will be easier to write your own reader, they're not too difficult. I too have a hatred of everything regex, but the good news is you can code any solution without ever using it.

A couple of things: There's a really weird thing Excel does to CSV files that begin with the two capital letters ID (without quotes). It thinks your CSV is a corrupted SYLK file! Try it.

For details of this issue and a detailed CSV File Format specification, please refer to http://mastpoint.curzonnassau.com/csv-1203